# D3 tooltip off the chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, d3.js

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Netdeamon/ddf498L7/1/).

```
  divs.on("mousemove", function() {
    var top = (d3.event.pageY) + "px";
    var left = (d3.event.pageX) + "px";
    console.log(top + " " + left);
    tooltip.style("top", top).style("left", left);
  });
```

I am using d3.event.pageX and pageY to get current position of mouse, **but still the tooltip doesnt attach to mouse.**

Comment: I added the extra d3.event.pageX - 200 in the fiddle just to show the drifting is proportional. As I hover from first bar to last bar, the tooltip drifts more and more apart. You can see the tooltip is on left, and then it goes to right, as you hover from first div to last div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css rule `charts.bar div:hover` you have a `zoom:150%;` line. This balloons out your tooltip's positioning by 50%, so it gets worse the further you move right; when you remove it the tooltip gets better. (You could also try out something like d3.tip (http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579) rather than rolling your own.)

Comment: I want the tooltip to stick to the mouse. One of the example I found was this  http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1087001 . But here too they use d3.event.pageX and pageY, which I am also using.

Comment: I came to know from the docs that pageX and pageY will return position of mouse. Correct me if I am wrong.